# Replacing two integers with their positive (absolute value) difference until getting a single number.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Say I have integers 1 through 100 on a blackboard. I choose two numbers to erase and replace those two numbers with the absolute value of the difference between the two. If I repeat this process until a single number remains, what is that number?

Comment: I don't think this number is uniquely determined. It will *always* be even, but it can be as high as $98$ or as low as $0$.

Comment: If we first choose all consecutive numbers, 50 ones remain. If we choose pairs of ones we end up with all zeroes, so the answer could be zero. On the other hand, if we choose all consecutive numbers except $1,100$, we get 49 ones and a $99$. That means that number remain can also be $98$. That is, there could be multiple answers to this question.

Comment: I don't believe it is uniquely determined.  For $6$ numbers, instead of $100$, we could pair consecutively, getting $(1,2), (3,4),(5,6)$ after which we have $\{1,1,1\}$ on the board...in which case the final result is $1$.  Or we could pair them as $(1,6),(2,5),(3,4)$ obtaining $\{5,3,1\}$  then pair $(3,1)$ to leave us with $\{5,2\}$ which results in $3$.   The parity is determined, but not the number itself.

Comment: @StinkingBishop can you explain why it would always be even?

Comment: @LorenzaFuller Because for any two integers $|x-y|\equiv x+y\pmod 2$ (because $x+y$ and $|x-y|$ are either both even or both odd). Thus, modulo $2$ it doesn't matter whether you take the modulus of the difference - or you just take the sum! However, the parity of the sum - in any order - is easily established: this is the parity of $1+2+\ldots+100=5050$, i.e. even.

Comment: BTW you tagged the question with contest-math - did it feature on some math competition before? Where did you get it from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you can say is that the result will be an even integer between $0$ and $98$.

First, the last number standing *must* be even:

> **Proof**: For any two integers, $|x-y|\equiv x+y\pmod 2$. This is true because $x+y$ and $|x-y|$ are either both even or both odd. Thus, modulo $2$
> it doesn't matter whether you take the absolute value of the difference - or
> you just take the sum! However, the parity of the sum - in any order -
> is easily established: this is the parity of $1+2+\ldots+100=5050$,
> i.e. even, q.e.d.

Also, by construction, any differences stay in the interval $[0,99]$, so the last number standing must be in that interval.

To prove that any even number (e.g. $2n$) between $0$ and $98$ can be obtained:

- Do the following subtractions: $(1,2n+2)\mapsto 2n+1, (2,3)\mapsto 1,\ldots (2n,2n+1)\mapsto 1, (2n+3, 2n+4)\mapsto 1, \ldots, (99,100)\mapsto 1$. We end up with one $2n+1$ and $49$ $1$'s.
- Then, turn those $49$ $1$'s into $24$ $0$'s and one $1$ (by mapping $(1,1)\mapsto 0$ $24$ times).
- Then, consume those $0$'s using $(1,0)\mapsto 1$ until we have only $1$ and $2n+1$
- Finally, map $(1,2n+1)\mapsto 2n$.